# How to use events in Google Charts to highlight elements in second graph?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to display 2 graphs of the same data: 1st graph is a stacked column chart and 2nd graph is a pie chart with data from the last column from the first graph.

I am only displaying the legend on the second graph as I don't want to show the same legend twice but then I lose the feature where column elements are highlighted when mouse hovers the legend. I am looking for code so that when I hover the mouse over the legend in the second graph, not only the pie chart will be highlighted but also associated elements in the column chart.

How can I implement this?

My code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <div id="chart1_div"></div>
<div id="chart2_div"></div>

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGraph);

function drawGraph() {
      var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]);
  var options1 = {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
  };

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Genre', 'Count'],
      ['Fantasy & Sci Fi', 28],
      ['Romance', 19],
      ['Mystery/Crime', 29],
      ['General', 30],
      ['Western', 12],
      ['Literature', 13]
    ]);

    var options2 = {
      title: 'Genres in 2030'
    };

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));

  var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart2_div'));

    chart1.draw(data1, options1);

    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
```

You can see my example in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h402tw3q/

Comment: highlightning is not possible via the API, to achieve it you would need a very complex handler which depends on the chartType and the features of the chart. The only thing that would be possible is to select a cell(as if you would click on a  chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easy. Set the `ColumnChart` to show its tooltip on selection :

```js
tooltip : { trigger : 'selection' }
```

and then update the selection for the `ColumnChart` each time the user `select` or `hover` on the `PieChart` or the PieChart `legend` :

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'onmouseover', function(selection) {
    chart2.setSelection(selection);
    chart1.setSelection([{ row: 2, column: selection.row+1 }]);
})
```

forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/eyft743w/**

`row` is hardcoded to `2` since the `PieChart` is associated with that row in the `ColumnChart`.

Comment: OK we're almost there, but since the legend is supposed to represent both graphs, I want all columns to be highlighted not just the last column.

Comment: OK. I got it working exactly like I need, also using onmouseout.
See https://jsfiddle.net/eyft743w/1/

Comment: @pdube, OK, great you got it to work - just took a chance by focusing on 2030 :) Thank you for accepting the answer.